# Moving Average plot

Tags: python, moving-average

I have a huge text file similar to the table in below link. Each xxx box has different number of lines but same number of column:

[Here is the link to figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6JEo.png)

- First point in the figure is the average of the first 3 values in the table,
- Second is the average of the first 5 values,
- Third is the average of first 8 values,
- and so on ...

I could not write a general python code which works for whole text file.
Could you please help me about that?

I tried this code but I got error:

Comment: What error?  Where?  On what data?

Comment: What error do you get? And where are these numbers 3,5,8 coming from? What's the rule for how many values to average?

Comment: 3,5,8 doesn't have an obvious "and so on"

Comment: Is it fibonacci? :-)

Comment: The table actually is a text file. Each XXXX is a cycle which generates several Energy value and I want to plot the averages as function of number of cycle.

Comment: the table in the link show three cycle: cycle one generates 3 values, cycle 2 generates 2 values and cycle 3 generates 3 values. I already made this text file. main point is how to calculate average of values as function of cycles.

Comment: Then you need to parse the text file and separate it into sections based on the xxxx. I see no attempt to do this in the code above.

Comment: Due to the xxxx I can not use it. I don't know how to count each cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the general layout of what you are looking for is:

```
with open('file','r') as file:
    groups = [] # Will contain the final data
    current_group = [] # Temporary

    line = file.readline()
    while line != "":
        if line == "XXXX":
            # Store the current group and start a new one
            groups.append(current_group)
            current_group = []
        else:
            # Add the number to the current group
            current_group.append(int(line.split()[2]))
        line = file.readline()
```

Comment: current_group.append(int(line.split()[2]))      :
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @AlirezaBahrami It means that there are less than 3 items (separated by spaces) on the line. You need to modify that line to do whatever data parsing is appropriate. I cant help you because I dont know the specifics of the input file.

Comment: Also, I was just trying to show how you would iterate through the lines adding to a group, and then start a new group each time a boundary is crossed.